# Evaluate outer xpath-expression in xpath-predicate

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, predicate

i have a problem with a xpath-statement.

Basically, the problem can be explained at the following code:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/b1im:B1IMessage/b1im:Header/b1im:Z/SortInbound/group">
                    <!-- Check if entry from duplicate table is found for the current AccountingEntry -->
                    <xsl:variable name="externalId" select="../externalId"></xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:value-of select="/b1im:B1IMessage/b1im:Body/b1im:Payload[@ObjectRole=&apos;CA&apos;]/jdbc:SqlResult/jdbc:ResultSet/jdbc:Row[jdbc:external_id= /../externalId]/jdbc:external_id"></xsl:value-of>
                    <xsl:variable name="group" select="./@id"></xsl:variable>                        
                    <!-- if it is no dupe => output -->
                     <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="/b1im:B1IMessage/b1im:Body/b1im:Payload[@ObjectRole=&apos;CA&apos;]/jdbc:SqlResult/jdbc:ResultSet/jdbc:Row[jdbc:external_id = ../externalId]/jdbc:external_id">
```

What I want to do is, use the value of "../externalId" (context of for-each) for a test (last line).. It would work if I used a variable ($externalId), but the variable is only set once (first loop iteration)... 
Is there a way how i can access the for-each-context in the xpath-expression?

Thanks in advance!!
Tobias

Comment: Adding `xslt` tag as this XPath expression is hosted by XSLT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On each step of XPath evaluation, the "`.`" (i.e. context node) has different meaning. In your XPath expression
`... jdbc:ResultSet/jdbc:Row[jdbc:external_id = ../externalId]` the context node in the predicate is determined by the previous steps in your XPath expression, so you are actually comparing to `externalID` child of the `jdbc:ResultSet` element. To compare to the value of `../externalID` of the for-each context node you could try using XSLT function `current()`.

`... jdbc:ResultSet/jdbc:Row[jdbc:external_id = current()/../externalId]`

Answer (score 1):

Two issues.

First, as @jasso has answered, when evaluating predicates the context is determined by last step. From http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#predicates

> A predicate filters a node-set with
>   respect to an axis to produce a new
>   node-set. For each node in the
>   node-set to be filtered, the
>   PredicateExpr is evaluated with that
>   node as the context node, with the
>   number of nodes in the node-set as the
>   context size, and with the proximity
>   position of the node in the node-set
>   with respect to the axis as the
>   context position

Second. You wrote:

> It would work if I used a variable
>   ($externalId), but the variable is
>   only set once (first loop
>   iteration)...

That's not true. The `for-each` content template is instantiated once for every node in its selected node set. Thus, `externalId` gets evaluate once for each of such nodes.

So, the right answer from @jasso:

```
... jdbc:ResultSet/jdbc:Row[jdbc:external_id = current()/../externalId]
```

Is the same as:

```
... jdbc:ResultSet/jdbc:Row[jdbc:external_id = $externalId]
```

Comment: @Alejandro, Good answer +1. In practice, when you have answered a question, I rarely haveto add anything to yoyr answer.

Comment: @Dimitre: Ja! Thanks! The same happens to me. ;)

Comment: Thanks to both of you, got it to work :) the method with the variable didn't worked for me in the first place because i had a fault in my input-xml.. Nevertheless, good to know the current()-function! Thanks